# Sum checkboxes using HTML value

Tags: html

Is there a way to use simple html to sum the values of the checkboxes without using any javascript to do that?

I need the most simple way of summing checked values.

I've been looking around and all I saw was some javascript on-click functions.

```js
var total = 0;
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="total" value="1" checked>1
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="total" value="2">2
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="total" value="3" checked>3
<div>
</div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="total" value="4">4
</div>

Total should be 4
```

Comment: *without using any javascript* no

Answer (score 1):

No. HTML is not a programming language. You can't do maths with it.

You need either:

- Client-side JavaScript to manipulate the DOM *or*
- A `<form>` to submit the data to a server-side program (which can be written in any programming language you like).